# Verifying counter falls in particular range or not in a packet capture

Tags: python, python-2.7, wireshark, pcap, packet-capture

I have got counters based on 2 sec interval.

- I need to verify that the count should be in range 1200 to 1600. Is there any way we can do it without parsing whole output?
- If for any particular time interval, the count doesn't fall into matching range, some error/warning message should get printed.
- Is there any method to get average for this counters?

```
# tshark -r q4-mme.pcap -qz io,stat,2,"COUNT(frame.time)frame.time"
===================================================================
IO Statistics
Interval: 2.000 secs
Column #0: COUNT(frame.time)frame.time
                |   Column #0
Time            |          COUNT
000.000-002.000              1241
002.000-004.000              1272
004.000-006.000              1315
006.000-008.000              1371
008.000-010.000              1195
010.000-012.000              1299
012.000-014.000              1305
014.000-016.000              1391
016.000-018.000              1463
018.000-020.000              1454
020.000-022.000              1392
022.000-024.000              1438
024.000-026.000              1362
026.000-028.000              1491
028.000-030.000              1392
030.000-032.000              1422
032.000-034.000              1425
034.000-036.000              1486
036.000-038.000              1449
038.000-040.000              1487
040.000-042.000              1402
042.000-044.000              1420
044.000-046.000              1330
046.000-048.000              1458
048.000-050.000              1420
050.000-052.000               144
===================================================================
```

Please let me know how can I achieve the desired results.

Comment: You should print your code, then your question can be referenced.

Comment: Code is up to writing a packet capture file and applying filter for getting counters per 2 seconds interval -> tshark -r q4-mme.pcap -qz io,stat,2,"COUNT(frame.time)frame.time". I want to know if there is any way other than regex to parse this output and get counters verified.

Comment: Yes, you can also write Python to process each line of output and determine the values. The problem doesn't seem to justify using regular expressions.

Comment: It will be really helpful if you can give a sample on how to start, the number of lines for intervals won't be fixed and I need to verify whether the counters fall into range or not and get the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with python. But here is an attempt using `awk`. You may call it from `python` using appropriate system commands.

**Verify the count range between 1200 to 1600**

```
awk '( $1~/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ && ($2<1200||$2>1600) ) {print $2}' file
```

Output:

```
1195
144
```

**Calculate Average**

```
awk '$1 ~ /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ {total+=$2; cnt++;} END {printf "Average = %.2f\n", total/cnt}' file
```

Output:

```
Average = 1339.38
```

Comment: Thanks jkshah for the crisp solution! It will do.